# Can we add more users in Google apps legacy free edition?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email, google-workspace-for-business

Can we add more users in Google apps legacy free edition ? Do I need to upgrade ? My domain is only with one user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Google Apps Free Edition (legacy)](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2855120?hl=en) the user limit is ten. If you have only one user, you should be able to add 9 more.

Comment: Whenever I login to gsuit admin with my legacy free account it redirects to a google products page. I am not not able to see add users option

Comment: You have to use the administrator account to access the admin panel.

Comment: ok. do they ask to upgrade to paid version when trying to add more users ?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way to add a user. I was one of the original founding business users and had up to 200 free users, can't even access the old legacy control panel anymore and I need to make a change. It wants me take the trial and I think that's the
 only way.